# How do you limit input to "yes" "no"

Tags: java, compiler-errors

If a user answers "yes" one of the 4 quotes print, randomly generate a number between 1 out of 4 and not print it, if a user answers "no" it prints "No quotes " and if it's neither it prints "Invalid", Should i use switch? if/else?
This is Java.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyedInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    String answer;
    System.out.println("Do you want to be inspired? (Enter Yes/No)");
    var Gen = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 + 1);
    answer = keyedInput.nextLine();

    if (answer.equals("Yes")) {
        System.out.println("Quote1");
    }

    else if (answer.equals("Yes")) {
        System.out.println("Quote2");
    }

    else if (answer.equals("Yes")) {
        System.out.println("Quote3");
    }

    else if (answer.equals("Yes")) {
        System.out.println("Quote3");
    }

    if (answer.equals("No")) {
        System.out.println("No quotes");
    }

    else {
        System.out.println("Invalid");
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use any code style you want, but if you write your code readably, people are more likely to manage to read it.

Comment: My bad khelwood, any tips on how i should make more readable? Just made my account

Comment: Don't put `}` on the end of lines. Especially `}}}`. Also use indentation consistently.

Comment: Ok, ill do that next time.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are trying to achieve:

```java
int Gen = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;


if(answer.equals("Yes")){
    switch(Gen){
        case 1: System.out.println("Quote 1"); break;
        case 2: System.out.println("Quote 2"); break;
        case 3: System.out.println("Quote 3"); break;
        case 4: System.out.println("Quote 4"); break;
    }
}else if(answer.equals("No")){
    System.out.println("No quotes");
}else{
    System.out.println("Invalid");
}
```

Comment: It says possible lossy conversion from double to int

Comment: On the switch gen

Comment: I couldn't be to detailed cause of Stack regulations but basically what i want is a Do you want to be inspired? the user replies with yes or no if they reply with yes it generates a random number (im not sure why this was asked) aswell as print one of the 4 quotes in my code. If the user replies with no, the program will print "no". and if the user replies with something thats not "yes" or "no" they get invalid

Answer (score 0):

This is a complex task: You want to ask the user yes/no, then if they answer neither 'yes' nor 'no', print something indicating that it's not valid *and ask again*.

So, make a method! And this method should loop - after all, it needs to keep doing the same thing, over and over again, until the user manages to provide a valid answer.

As a side-note, never use `.nextLine()`, it doesn't do what you think it does. Only use `.next()` if you want a string, `.nextInt()` if you want an int, etcetera. If you want whole lines of input (and you usually do), after making your scanner configure it to read lines at a time with `scanner.useDelimiter("\\R");`

```
public static boolean askBoolean(String prompt, Scanner scanner) {
    while (true) {
        System.out.print(prompt + " (yes/no): ");
        String answer = scanner.next();
        if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) return true;
        if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("No")) return false;
        System.out.println("Please enter yes or no.");
    }
}
```

Let's not use a switch, because `equalsIgnoreCase` sounds useful here.

and to use:

```
boolean wantsToBeInspired = askBoolean("Do you want to be inspired?", scanner);

if (wantsToBeInspired) {
    showAQuote();
} else {
    System.out.println("No quote for you");
}
```

Comment: should not use OS dependent new line delimiter ("\\R"), use the one provided by the system: System.lineSeparator()

Comment: I couldn't be to detailed cause of Stack regulations but basically what i want is a Do you want to be inspired? the user replies with yes or no if they reply with yes it generates a random number (im not sure why this was asked) aswell as print one of the 4 quotes in my code. If the user replies with no, the program will print "no". and if the user replies with something thats not "yes" or "no" they get invalid

Comment: @AndriusBurokas `\\R` _is_ the proper way. Look it up, I didn't write `\r`. `\\R` means something else in regexpese (basically, line separator).

Comment: @NeymarJr ... and this answer does exactly what you want.